# How to resize image before adding into xml file

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have many bitmaps in my xml file and I'm getting an out of memory exception.

I have this code to resize the bitmaps to reduce the space.

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res,
            int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }
```

How can I use this code to resize the images in my drawable folder BEFORE they are added in the xml file so I dont get an out of memory exception?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this,

```
return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options), reqWidth, reqHeight, false);
```

your image will follow the size of your reqWidth and reqHeight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this ...

```
Bitmap decodedBitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myImage, 100, 100); //100x100 should be imageView display size.
imgView.setImageBitmap(decodedBitmap);
```